# Reports/Visualization on top of Databricks SQL Analytics(Redash) query history?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, redash, databricks-sql

Is it possible to directly query the query history (logs) from Databricks SQL Analytics workspace and develop some reports on query metrics?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately,  you cannot create Reports/Visualization on top of Databricks SQL Analytics(Redash) query history.

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://databricks.com/feedback

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Query History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/query-history) and [Redash: Easily Visualize, Dashboard, and Share your Data](https://databricks.com/session_na20/redash-easily-visualize-dashboard-share-data)